# Android Form data to JSONObjects

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, json

I have an Android form that gets data from a user. I have all the data in a bundle. But I need help on how to store the bundle into `JSONObjects`. The code below gets the data and stores it into a `Bundle`

```
    Fragment data = new Fragment();
    Bundle itembundle =new Bundle();        
    itembundle.putString("title",title.getText().toString());
    itembundle.putString("subject",subject.getText().toString());
    itembundle.putString("content", content.getText().toString());
    itembundle.putString("source", source.getText().toString());
    if (title.getText()!=null && subject.getText() != null&&      content.getText()!= null && source.getText()!= null ){
        data.setArguments(itembundle);
        title.setText("");
        subject.setText("");
        content.setText("");
        source.setText("");
    } else{
          //code to throw exception of an empty form element
    }
```

And the code below gets the data from the bundle.

```
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle getData = this.getArguments();
    if (getArguments()!=null){
        item.setItemTitle((String) getData.getCharSequence("title"));
        item.setItemContent((String) getData.getCharSequence("subject"));
        item.setItemDescription((String) getData.getCharSequence("content"));
        itemList.add(item);
    }

}
```

So please help me on how to put this into a `JSONObjects`. Thanks.

Comment: what do you need actually ? Use JSONObject instade of Bundle or want to use both ..

Comment: I ma really new to Android. So I started with using bundle first. So i want to know how to use JSONObject so as to send it to the web.

Comment: @Jeremiah If you want to send it to web, create JSONObject like I have shown in my Answer, then convert it to String, and you can send it to web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you simply mean you want to create a JSONObject with these values?
Did you try this:

```
JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
try{
    info.put("title",getData.getCharSequence("title"));
    info.put("subject",getData.getCharSequence("subject")););
}catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thats it, you now have a JSONObject.

You can also create an Array of Information like this:

```
JSONObject info1 = new JSONObject();
info1.put("firstName","newFirstName");
info1.put("lastName","newLastName");

JSONObject info2 = new JSONObject();
info2.put("firstName","newFirstName");
info2.put("lastName","newLastName");

JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray();
myArray.put(info1);
myArray.put(info2);

JSONObject newObj = JSONObject();
newObj.put(myArray);
```

Comment: I really don't understand the public method `info.add(),` is it a public method in JSONObjects?

Comment: Sorry I messed it up with the `ArrayList`. In JSON we have `put` method. I have edited my andwer

Answer (score 2):

For each item in the list you need to do some like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObj.put("title", item.getItemTitle());
    jsonObj.put("content", item.getItemContent());
    jsonObj.put("description", item.getItemDescription());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Another way is to use gson, given the item object, you only need to call

```
String jsonString = gson.toJson(item)
```

Here is the developer guide for Gson
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
try
   {

      JSONObjects json =new JSONObjects(); 
      json.put(Key,value);
      json.put(Key,value);
      //and pass the data 
      Bundle itembundle =new Bundle();  
        itembundle.putString("items",json.toString());


    //and get data 

    JSONObjects json=new JSONObjects(getArguments().getString("items"));
    String title=json.getString(Key);   



   }catch (Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

For fresh JSONObject its easy .. try this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try{

jsonObject.put("key","value");
........
//for your case it would be like this
jsonObject.put("title",title.getText().toString());


}catch(JSONException ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
}

String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
Log.e("json",jsonString);
```

Now you able to see the jsonString in your logcat.